# How to validate email on backend (Rails) and allow not to fill this field in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm working on a simple one-page contact form. Contact model have two attributes: phone and email. Email should be validated on backend (i did it in my model). But user can fill either email or phone in the contact form and send it. No Email field in necessary and i don't know how to make it optional.

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
attribute :phone
attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i, 
                      presence: false

def headers
  {
    :subject => "My Contact Form",
    :to => "email@admin.com",
    :from => %("#{phone}" <#{email}>)
  }
end
```

end

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @contact = Contact.new
   end

   def create
     @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
     @contact.request = request
     if @contact.deliver
       flash.now[:notice] = 'Ваша заявка принята!'
       render :new
     else
       flash.now[:notice] = 'Введите корректный email.'
       render :new
     end
   end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:phone, :email)
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <%= f.input_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "email", required: false %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <%= f.input_field :phone, class: "form-control", placeholder: "+7 (095) 123-45-67" %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit', :class=> "btn btn-success" %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
              <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                 <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does this mean the user could either enter the phone or email, while one is required to pass? Or you just want to validate the email if it's present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go about it this way:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :phone
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i, 
                      presence: false, allow_blank: true
  validate :at_least_a_contact

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "email@admin.com",
      :from => %("#{phone}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
  private
    def at_least_a_contact
      unless phone.present? || email.present?
        errors.add(:contact, "You need at least a contact method")
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `allow_blank: true` in your validation in your model.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank